# Set python virtualenv in vim

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, macvim

I use vim for coding and for python coding in particular. Often I want to execute the current buffer with python interpreter. (for example to run unittests), usually I do this with `:!python % <Enter>`

This scenatio will work works fine with global python, but I want to run virtualenv python instead. How do I enable virtualenv within vim? Is it possible to switch virtualenv on the runtime?

I'm using macvim

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's what I use (sorry the highlighting is screwy).

```
" Function to activate a virtualenv in the embedded interpreter for
" omnicomplete and other things like that.
function LoadVirtualEnv(path)
    let activate_this = a:path . '/bin/activate_this.py'
    if getftype(a:path) == "dir" && filereadable(activate_this)
        python << EOF
import vim
activate_this = vim.eval('l:activate_this')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
EOF
    endif
endfunction

" Load up a 'stable' virtualenv if one exists in ~/.virtualenv
let defaultvirtualenv = $HOME . "/.virtualenvs/stable"

" Only attempt to load this virtualenv if the defaultvirtualenv
" actually exists, and we aren't running with a virtualenv active.
if has("python")
    if empty($VIRTUAL_ENV) && getftype(defaultvirtualenv) == "dir"
        call LoadVirtualEnv(defaultvirtualenv)
    endif
endif
```

Note that you need to have MacVim compiled against the Python you are using for the virtualenv, e.g. if you downloaded Python 2.7 from Python.org you should recompile MacVim using `--with-python-config-dir=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config` as an argument to `./configure`.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** Just one note of attribution: A lot of the detective work that went into writing this little ditty was done by [this blogger](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/04/21/vim-autocomplete-django-and-virtualenv/), and he deserves some of the credit.

Comment: wow, cool, this is what I was looking for, thanks a lot! I didn't know virtualenv creates this activate_this.py

Comment: Hi dwf, could you take a look at my question here to see why my output is weird? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288843/macvim-uses-wrong-python-virtualenv

Comment: In Python 3: `exec(open(activate_this).read(), { "__file__": activate_this })`

Answer (score 22):

Activate your virtualenv before starting vim. You will automatically get the corresponding interpreter instance.

Comment: I'm using MacVim, and I start it from the Dock, so it's not really a good option... As far as I understand activating the virtualenv is all about modifying the PATH, PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH env vars, maybe some other too. I dont mind to port the virtualenv's activate `script` to vim, I was just wondering if there is an existing solution.

Comment: I'm finding this doesn't work if the virtualenv python is a different version from the vim-compiled one (eg 2 vs 3)

Answer (score 3):

There is also a vim plugin on github:

https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv

I have not tried it, but it seems to solve the question as well.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work on Mac OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion) -- some other underlying issue perhaps exists

Comment: @Chris: This is most likely because of  [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853584/how-to-use-correct-ruby-in-vim-how-to-modify-path-in-vim/12146694#12146694).

Comment: Worked perfectly!  But you may have to set `g:virtualenv_directory'.`
E.g. for me: `let g:virtualenv_directory = '~/.local/share/virtualenvs'`


----
For more info check from inside vim/nvim: `:h virtualenv` after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function with an alias for vim to auto load/unload the virtualenv if it exists at the location from which you start it.

In this example, it checks for the virtualenv in `.venv/bin/activate`.

```sh
vimVenAutoload() {
    if [ -e .venv/bin/activate ]; then
        . .venv/bin/activate;
        vim $*;
        deactivate;
    else
        vim $*;
    fi;
}
alias vim="vimVenAutoload"
```

You can add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Small caveat: If a virtualenv is already loaded, it will be overwritten with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

this issue actually bothered me for a long time until I use the plugin of vim-conda. Just add Plugin 'cjrh/vim-conda' in your ~/.vimrc and it will work. You can also see the detailed instruction https://github.com/cjrh/vim-conda.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reasons you do not want to run `vim` inside a python virtual environment, then instead of sourcing `venv/bin/activate`, you can:

```sh
PYTHONPATH="$(source venv/bin/activate; python3 -c "import sys; print(':'.join(sys.path))"; deactivate)" vim
```

which also kinda source the virtual environment, but it keeps it *somewhat* separate from the environment in which `vim` is run.