# How do i get macvim to recognize a python virtualenv automatically?

Tags: python, virtualenv, macvim

I use macvim built with python interpreter support on OS X lion for python coding. 
In order for omnicompletion to work with the libraries for a particular python 
virtualenv I would like macvim to recognize that it is opened within an activated 
python virtualenv.

On Ubuntu this works exactly like i expect it to; 
If I open vim in and activate virtualenv, all libs specific to that virtualenv are on Python's 
path. This does not work in macvim when launch from the mvim shell script inside an 
activated virtualenv.  Instead, the Python path consists of the global Python's libs.

I know there is a way around this with some semi heavy vim-scripting, but I would 
prefer it if it behaves like on Ubuntu. I would at least want to know why it doesn't 
behave that way. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Identical question in SO. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881534/set-python-virtualenv-in-vim][1]. It actually shows it for Macvim.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881534/set-python-virtualenv-in-vim