# How to use correct ruby in vim ? How to modify $PATH in VIM?

Tags: ruby, vim, osx-lion, rbenv

I use plain Vim with ruby support on Lion (installed by [gist](https://gist.github.com/1110471)). I am using ruby with rbenv so my path looks like /users/me/.rbenv/shims:.....

From within vim the path is

```
:!echo $PATH
> usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/fb/.rbenv/shims:....
```

Even I can create and modify an environment variable:

```
:let $PATH = "/bar:/foo"
:!echo $PATH
> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/foo:/bar
```

paths remains starting with /usr/bin.

So how can I access my ruby 1.9.3 in ~/.rbenv/shims instead the system ruby in /usr/bin ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did'n t set the `shell` option in .vimrc, so that it was automatically set to `/bin/zsh`.

Then I found out that I hab a dublicate initialisation of rbenv: in my .zshrc. I removed the initialisation end $PATH extensioin in `.zshrc` because that was already handled by the oh-my-zsh rbenv  plugin.

Even after that cleanup, the $PATH mangeling still happening so `:!echo $PATH`

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/fb/.rbenv/shims:/Users/fb/.rbenv/bin:/Users/fb/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/games

Setting `:set shell=/bin/bash` was what helped me, as i can live with bash in my vim:  `:!echo $PATH`

> /Users/fb/.rbenv/shims:/Users/fb/.rbenv/bin:/Users/fb/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/Users/fb/Dropbox/local/bash

Answer (score 30):

This is [a known problem introduced by Apple in OS X 10.5 Leopard](https://github.com/dotphiles/dotzsh#mac-os-x).

If you are using Bash or Zsh and are using non-interactive shells, you are affected.

Running `sudo chmod ugo-x /usr/libexec/path_helper` will fix you up, but you should take a look at the article to see why.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. But I found the suggestion provided by tpope's [vim-rbenv](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rbenv#faq) to be a better one because it still enables the execution of the `path_helper` on interactive shells. Simply `sudo mv /etc/zshenv /etc/zshrc` and vim says Yay!

Comment: This really can't get enough upvotes. This is the second time I've come here because how in the world could anyone remember they need to do this when setting up an environment.

Comment: I get `chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/libexec/path_helper: Operation not permitted` error when I run this command. Any pointers.

Comment: @Zuhaib are you using `sudo`?

Comment: @EdwardOcampo-Gooding I am using sudo and I also have Zuhaib's issue.

Answer (score 5):

rvm also has this problem. If zsh is your default shell when it starts `/etc/zshenv` gets executed.

This executes `/usr/libexec/path_helper`. That sets up the path based on the contents `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/`.

The [faq for rvm](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rvm) mentions moving `/etc/zshenv` to `/zsh/zshrc`. I did this and it removed the `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` from the start of my path in macvim.

Comment: I altered `/etc/paths` and that worked for me. **Thank you!** This is great to know.

Answer (score 2):

In your ~/.bashrc (or whatever shell you're using) file, add the following line:

```
PATH=/home/me/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}
```

and then run `source ~/.bashrc` (or .zshrc or whatever shell you're using!)

Comment: If you put that in `~/.bash_profile` you won't have to run the source command (it will automatically run that command every time you start a new shell)

Comment: True - didn't think of that. Though you'll only need to run the source command once for each shell you had open when you edited ~/.bashrc. In my head I was translating from zsh to bash - I really just wanted to tell him to put it in his ~/.zshrc :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I use zsh and have no .bashrc nor .bash_profile. For testing i created them, but it doesn't help. I use zsh and my path is set correct both in Terminal and Iterm2.

Comment: in zsh `echo $PATH` >/Users/fb/.rbenv/shims:... in `vim` `:set shell?` >shell=/bin/zsh, `:echo $PATH` >/Users/fb/.rbenv/shims:... but `:!echo $PATH` >/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/fb/.rbenv/shims:... and so `:!ruby -v`>ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0] and not the fancy 1.9.3, :( ????

Comment: Based on the installation instructions (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#section_2), it looks like you should have <code>/home/me/.rbenv/bin</code> in your path, not <code>/home/me/.rbenv/shims</code>. You could also give rvm a shot - I have no issues with it on Lion (https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by just adding

```
PATH=/home/me/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}
```

to

```
/etc/zshenv
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use mac or zsh (I am on linux), however I ran into this problem when I ran gvim from the MATE Menu.

I solved it by adding this to my .vimrc:

```
if $PATH !~ "\.rbenv"
    let $PATH="/home/username/.rbenv/shims:/home/username/.rbenv/bin:" . $PATH
endif
```

This avoids setting it if you run vim from a terminal, otherwise the rbenv paths would be included twice.

I tried setting the application to run via a terminal, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

yes on OS X it's the bash_profile that gets sourced when opening a new console window whereas on Linux it's your bashrc