# Alter $PATH in vim/macvim so as to find the right ruby binary

Tags: ruby, vim, zsh, macvim

In trying to harmonize environments between a ZSH session and the vim/macvim access of the shell, a `which ruby` from the shell shows *$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby*, which is good, while from inside vim/macvim a `!which ruby` shows */opt/local/bin/ruby*, which is bad.

I thought copying the invocation of RVM from .zshrc to .zshenv would work but doing so interferes with other utilities. After several days trying to sort this out, I feel stumped. Any suggestions of where documentation to resolve this can be found would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious what utilities were interfered with when adding rvm to your .zshenv.  The documentation at the rvm site suggests that using the .zshenv should fix this issue https://rvm.io/integration/vim/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it applies to zsh but depending on how it's started, bash reads some files and not others. Having this line in my `~/.vimrc` ensures that `$PATH` is the same in Vim and in my shell.

```
set shell=bash\ -i
```

But it depends on how you start/customize your shell.

See `:help 'shell'` and zsh's manual.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given here worked for me pretty well:

[How to use correct ruby in vim ? How to modify $PATH in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9853584/2279720)

And the explanation given for the different $PATH in interactive and non-interactive mode is straightforward:

https://github.com/dotphiles/dotzsh#mac-os-x

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `:$PATH=$HOME.'/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby:'.$PATH` in your vimrc.  Probably hacky, but maybe it'll work.

Comment: Maybe. If I can fully import the shell environment into the vim/macvim session, though, it would be a lot cleaner, though.

Comment: Just tried this. No dice. I received
`E15: Invalid expression: .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby:$PATH
E15: Invalid expression: $HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby:$PATH`
when trying to source the .vimrc.

Comment: @xuinkrbin. ; @synic Invalid syntax, you should have used `let $PATH=$HOME.'/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby:'.$PATH`.