# $PATH in vim is different from which in shell? (Mac OSX)

Tags: vim, environment-variables

As you know that the ctags in OSX is a basic version, and I install a full version of ctags using homebrew, but when I wanna use it in Vim's command mode, it always ran the basic one. So I checked the $PATH var in Vim's command mode, like `!echo $PATH`, and it showed that `/usr/local/bin` followed the `/usr/bin`, which was different from the shell environment $PATH, so please kindly tell me how to fix this， many thanks!.
BTW, I changed the $PATH in vimrc file, but it only affected the $PATH if I type the command `echo $PATH` in Vim's command mode, not `!echo $PATH`.

Comment: do you use graphical vim or terminal vim?

Comment: How do you set `PATH` in your shell environment?

Comment: graphical vim and terminal vim have the same issue.

Comment: do you change your `$PATH` variable in `./bashrc` or `./profile`?

Comment: I reset my $PATH in .zshrc. Actually if I did not reset the $PATH, the  PATH would be ```/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin```, I do not know when and where this var was set.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553875/alter-path-in-vim-macvim-so-as-to-find-the-right-ruby-binary/10554411#10554411).

Comment: also see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45723/gvim-pipes-not-reading-zshrc-when-started-from-desktop)

Comment: thanks @gokcehan, your solution totally works. Change the $PATH in .zshenv should be the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MacVim won't be affected by paths you set in `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

You can set paths affecting all programs on Mac OS X by using the `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` mechanisms. More detailed explanation here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x