# turn on/install ctags in Macvim (having installed homebrew, oh-my-zsh, janus)

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, homebrew, ctags

I installed macvim using homebrew on my Mackbook Pro (lion). once that was installed I installed janus. I also installed oh-my-zsh (if that helps solve this problem).
I can't seem to get ctags working though. In MacVim when I do Tools>Build Tags File I get:

```
:!ctags -R .
ctags: illegal option -- R
usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...

shell returned 1 
Press RETURN or type command to continue
```

How do I get it to work?

Here's some additional info that may help you:

```
✗ ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jul  7 2012, 01:00:53
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex

✗ which ctags
/usr/local/bin/ctags 

✗ echo $path
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gemset/bin /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin /Users/adam/.rvm/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/X11/bin /Users/adam/.rvm/bin
```

Answer (score 7):

It definitely looks like Vim is picking up /usr/bin/ctags, which doesn't recognize `-R`, instead of /usr/local/bin/ctags. This can happen if put /usr/local/bin in your path only for login shells.

You might want to make sure /usr/local/bin gets added to your path in the non-login, non-interactive environment file. I don't use zsh myself, but it looks like that would be .zshenv.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, by default the path that vim uses and the path that the terminal (bash/zsh) uses are different, so even if you have the correct path set in the terminal, it won't translate to vim correctly, to rectify this situation, you need to run

```
sudo chmod ugo-x /usr/libexec/path_helper
```

For more information see: [How to use correct ruby in vim ? How to modify $PATH in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853584/how-to-use-correct-ruby-in-vim-how-to-modify-path-in-vim).