# Why does my vim command-line path differ from my shell PATH?

Tags: vim, command-line, path

e.g.,

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/bin

$ vim 
:! echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/bin
```

I expected them to be the same.  Why are they different?

If it makes a difference, here is my shell, vim version and OS version:

```
$ echo $SHELL
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh

$ /usr/local/bin/zsh --version
zsh 5.0.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0)

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 20 2012 13:16:02)
Compiled by root@apple.com


$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.2
BuildVersion:   12C60

(Mountain Lion)
```

Comment: How do you launch vim? And what is the output of `echo &shell` in vim? Do they differ if you do `set shellcmdflag=-ic` and then `!echo $SHELL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to resolve this with zsh, and ended up using bash for my vim shell.

Here's what I did:

1. modified my `.zshrc` to work with `bash`
2. `ln -s .zshrc .bashrc`
3. added `set shell=bash` to my `.vimrc` file

and now my vim command-line PATH is equal to my zsh shell PATH.

Answer (score 12):

> This is a [known
>   problem](https://github.com/dotphiles/dotzsh#mac-os-x) introduced by
>   Apple in OS X 10.5 Leopard.
>
> If you are using Bash or Zsh and are using non-interactive shells, you
>   are affected.
>
> Running `sudo chmod ugo-x /usr/libexec/path_helper` will fix you up,
>   but you should take a look at the article to see why.

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146694/600953)

Answer (score 4):

There are many similar questions on stackoverflow and stackexchange.

Your shell executes different *rc files depending on the arguments its given at launch time. Therefore, you need to setup Vim so that it launchs your shell with the right arguments.

The following helps in bash, I'm almost certain there's a similar flag in zsh.

```
set shell=bash\ -i
```

See `$ man zsh` for the right flag and the right execution order.

Comment: It is exactly the same there, zsh was meant to be compatible with POSIX. But `shell` is not a right place for setting interactive flag, there is `shellcmdflag`.

Comment: You are right. Why don't you turn your comment into a proper answer?

Comment: Because without the feedback from author I can’t be sure it is the right answer. It may appear that some plugin changes $PATH or shell is actually different, or that vim is launched from a shortcut (and maybe is actually mvim); on my system the fact that some components of $PATH are defined in zshrc and shell is not interactive does not prevent $PATH from being the same: it is just inherited from environment, not constructed using rc files. In fact, there are *no* rc files that are sourced by non-interactive shell (/etc/zsh/zshenv and ~/.zshenv are missing, others are not sourced).

Comment: Thanks @romaini.  I could not find the equivalent for zsh.  `bash -i` gives me undesired behavior if the command fails, so I just went with bash (without the `-i`).

Answer (score -1):

I don't use mac or zsh (I am on linux), however I ran into this problem when I ran gvim from the MATE Menu.

I solved it by adding this to my .vimrc:

```
if $PATH !~ "\.rbenv"
    let $PATH="/home/username/.rbenv/shims:/home/username/.rbenv/bin:" . $PATH
endif
```

This avoids setting it if you run vim from a terminal, otherwise the rbenv paths would be included twice.

I tried setting the application to run via a terminal, but that didn't help.