# why $PATH in vim and in zsh is different?

Tags: ruby, vim, path

in my rails app folder foo , `ruby -v` is `ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]`, but open foo in vim, `:!ruby -v` is `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]`.

anyone can help ?

thanks !

Comment: Are you perhaps using some kind of virtual environment (like python's `virtualenv`, don't know how it's called in ruby), maybe `rvm`? Have you checked the output of `echo $PATH` (in your shell) and `:!echo $PATH` (in vim)?

Comment: @NadirSampaoli echo $PATH in vim and in shell is different, i use oh-my-zsh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my vim command-line path differ from my shell PATH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402899/why-does-my-vim-command-line-path-differ-from-my-shell-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, did you write $PATH in `.zshrc`? If so, you should use `.zshenv`.

`.zshrc` is not loaded when called script commands from vim and some applications.

Or you're using zsh on OS X. You should move /etc/zshenv to /etc/zshrc.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your shell vim uses for running commands:

```
set shell=/bin/sh
```

You can just put it into your ~/.vimrc or run manually to test it first.

This way you will get the same environment in vim as with your interactive shell.