# Ctags path in vim is different from the shell

Tags: vim, path, ctags

I was trying to generate the ctags from vim. I use Exuberant ctags.

So the problem is that when I do `:!ctags` or `:call system('ctags')` from vim it does not work because it uses my default ctags and not the exuberant ctags.
I had similar problem in my shell which I overcame by specifying the path of exuberant first 
like `export PATH=/usr/bin/local/:$PATH`
So here is the really weird part
When I do `echo $PATH` in vim it shows the correct path. But When I do `:call system('which ctags')`
it shows me `/usr/bin/ctags` and not `/usr/bin/local/ctags`.
I can't understand what is going on??

Though I can overcome this problem by `call system('/usr/bin/local/ctags')` but I was just wondering if there is something better out there.

EDIT:
I use OSX 10.9.3

`:set shell?` -> `shell=/bin/zsh`

`set shellcmdflag` -> `shellcmdflag=-c`

and I set my path in zshrc file as `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:usr/local:$PATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `:!command` or `:call system('command')` Vim starts a new subshell according to the values of `'shell'` and a bunch of other options listed under `:help 'shell'`. The `'shellcmdflag'` option is important because it usually tells your shell how to start (interactive or not, login or not) which usually has an impact on what `*rc` files are sourced and thus if your environment variables are seen or not.

Please, update your question with these informations:

- your OS
- `:set shell?`
- `:set shellcmdflag?`
- in what `*rc` file did you change your `PATH`?

Comment: That was really helpful! I found out that my os was corrupting the $PATH even before my zshrc was sourced. as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853584/how-to-use-correct-ruby-in-vim-how-to-modify-path-in-vim/12146694#12146694

Comment: I just have one little question though, is is possible to source my current shell path (from where I start my vim ) to vim, because virtualenv changes the $PATH variable and then vim starts a new shell and does not see that. I know other ways to get around it but was just wondering if there is something better?!! like setting the path when with the shell command or someting?!

Comment: Yes, it is a common issue on Mac OS X. It's relatively easy to fix if you don't play with your `PATH` every day but virtualenv sure makes the whole thing more complicated than it should. As a workaround, you can adjust your path before calling a shell command: `$ export FOO="foo" && echo $FOO`.