# MacVim uses wrong Python Virtualenv

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, macvim

I want to use the virtualenv's python to execute the current buffer using  `:!python % <Enter>`.  However, MacVim uses the system python instead of the virtualenv's python.

I've implemented [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881534/set-python-virtualenv-in-vim), but `:!python %<Enter>` still doesn't behave properly.  Here's an example of what I mean -- these commands have the virtualenv activated (managed with virtualenvwrapper, it that matters)

- In the shell: `which python` -->
  `/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin/python` --> OK
- MacVim: `:python import sys; print sys.executable<Enter>` -->
  `/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin/python` --> OK
- MacVim: `:!which python<Enter>` --> `/usr/bin/python` --> NOT OK

Since the last one is most similar to how I'm executing the buffer, could you help explain how I can achieve `:!python %<Enter>` in MacVim using the existing virtualenv's python?

EDIT: Also, I have this alias to use a command-line MacVim:

`alias vim=/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`

Also, this is the output of `:echo $PATH<Enter>` in MacVim:

- MacVim: `:echo $PATH<Center>`

`/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin:/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin:/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin:/Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myuser/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/Users/myuser/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/java/bin:/usr/lib64/java/jre/bin:/usr/lib64/java/bin:/usr/lib64/kde4/libexec:/opt/kde3/lib64/qt3/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin:.:/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/bin`

Comment: In MacVim, what is the output of `:echo $PATH`?

Comment: /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin:/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin:/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/MyVirtualEnv/bin:/Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myuser/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/Users/myuser/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/java/bin:/usr/lib64/java/jre/bin:/usr/lib64/java/bin:/usr/lib64/kde4/libexec:/opt/kde3/lib64/qt3/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin:.:/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/bin

Comment: Are you using Homebrew? You should a) upgrade to a more recent Vim, b) use the Homebrew issue tracker.