# Vim Pymode don't use actual env

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, python-mode

After my env is activated, I start vim. In the bottom of the screen I see something like this:
"[Pymode] Activate virtualenv: /home/../envs/test_env"
When I'm trying to run my script, vim use system base python, but not from my env.
I have in my settings "let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1"
What is the problem?

Comment: Python-mode uses the Python interpreter Vim is linked against, not your system python.  Of course, this is relevant only if the two are different.

Comment: how did you try to run your script? if you do `:!python your_script.py` then it's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is far from optimal but here it goes:

When it comes to efficiently switching between python2 and python3 venvs the main problem seems to be the fact that (I am quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881534/set-python-virtualenv-in-vim) reply)

> you need to have MacVim compiled against the Python you are using for
>   the virtualenv

Of course it does not seem to be a mac-only issue; vim cannot support both python2 and python3 (e.g. [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182161)).

So a proposed workaround (which for the moment seems to be ok for me) is:

**a**. completely uninstall any existing vim installations to set the environment from scratch

**b**. set up a vim installation with python3 support as indicated [here](http://www.xorpd.net/blog/vim_python3_install.html)

**c**. sudo apt-get install vim-gnome (installs a python2 compliant vim)

**d**. set up your ~/.vimrc and the plugins in ~/.vim folder as indicated in this nice [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g)

**e**. (I assume this should not be needed but for some reason - perhaps my fault - given that python-mode plugin is supposed to come with virtualenv support): install virtualenv plugin for vim from [here](https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv). (it is then when I got access to commands such as `:VirtualEnvList`, `:VirtualEnvActivate` etc)

**f**. create 2 aliases in your .bashrc for the two vim installations of step b and c.

-> `alias vim3="/opt/vim74/bin/vim"` (this came from step b)

-> `alias vim2="/usr/bin/vim"` (this came from step c)

**g**. add the following line to your .vimrc:
    `let g:virtualenv_directory = "~/path/to/my/venvs"`

**h**. switch to your venv dir, activate it and start the appropriate vim2/3. now presumably you will be able to use venvs through the appropriate commands e.g. `:VirtualEnvList` etc...

hope that helps and also hope someone comes up with s.th more efficient...